# Two PHP Values in Array

Tags: php, database, arrays, wordpress

I have a value from a option field:

The value being pulled from the data base looks like this `$value = $this->value;`.

Then I can update the value like this:

```
<textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'[]" name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]" rows="6" class="'.$class.'" />'.esc_attr($value).'</textarea>
```

What I want to do is to add another text area field below the first one, and for it to save both values in the database. I can copy and paste the above code, and it updates my array. But the values don't show inside the field itself, the field is empty. Any clue on what I should do?

Comment: This looks like a problem: `/>`  Is that a typo?  It self-closes the `textarea` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt see that. It didnt make a difference with the code above though. I'm using `print_r()` to show my array above, and when i update both textarea boxes, the array is updated as well. But the boxes are empty

Comment: Could `esc_attr` be returning `null` or an empty string somehow?

Comment: Please paste the html line generated by that echo, that will tell the problem

Comment: Its tough to understand the format you are trying to print. Did you try `sprintf` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback,

I used `array_chunk` to fix my problem

```
if(isset($this->value) {
$chunk = array_chunk($value,2);

foreach($chunk as $k => $value){

<textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'[]" name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]" rows="6" class="'.$class.'" >'.esc_attr($value[0]).'</textarea>

<textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'[]" name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]" rows="6" class="'.$class.'" >'.esc_attr($value[1]).'</textarea>

}

} else {

<textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'[]" name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]" rows="6" class="'.$class.'" >'.esc_attr($value).'</textarea>

<textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'[]" name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]" rows="6" class="'.$class.'" >'.esc_attr($value).'</textarea>

}
```